# How should I structure my WordPress categories/tags for SEO?

Tags: wordpress, seo

I have a trance music website located at http://trancefanatic.com. There are currently two categories: Trance DJs and Trance Vocalists. Underneath each of those are the corresponding names. For tags, I've been using things like "lyrics", "music video", etc. However, I also noticed that I've been using the artists' names as tags, IN ADDITION to having them as sub-categories.

I've read that this is bad for SEO. I'm not sure what would be the best way to re-structure my categories/tags, without losing traffic. My website basically provides trance/vocal trance music, as well as lyrics.

Any suggestions would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: If you haven't already installed one of the popular SEO plug-ins for WordPress, you should do so.  They do a good job of helping you nail the SEO basics.  My experience is that it's much more important to focus on your content than on category/tag metadata.

Comment: I actually already installed the SEO plugin by Yoast. But I wasn't sure if I needed to re-structure the way my categories/tags were as well...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, install SEO plugin for Wordpress like `Wordpress SEO by Yoast` (the best in my opinion).

Secondly, you should choose `noindex, follow` for tags or categories (as you wish) but choose one to avoid [duplicate content](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&hlrm=fr&answer=66359) that is bad for SEO.

You don't need to re-structure your website with this process.